# How can i get a signer to sign a document using a custom link by passing their email or id?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk, e-signature

Elaborating my question
1. I  have a quickstart app with app_url : http://localhost/docusign_affiniks-php/public
2. I have a codeignator app with url : http://localhost/affiniks_staging/affiniks/app/

both running in xaamp server.

i need to get users inside my codeignator app to click on a link which will take them to the document created inside the quickstart app using their email or id so that they can sign it ,how am i supposed to do that?

I tried merging both apps,running them in the xaamp at the same time but all i am able to do is simply login and sign a document myself.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) you downloaded only includes a basic code example that shows how to sing yourelf.

To have a different signer, you need to modify the code, to include their information.

The code example for PHP you have in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/EmbeddedSigningService.php has this snippet that you'll need to modify:

```
$signer = new Signer(
    [ # The signer
        'email' => $args['signer_email'],
        'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "1",
        'routing_order' => "1",
        # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
        'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
    ]
);
```

You should be able to get that code into your other app, get the information about who the signer is and get them to sign.

Note that if you meant to have it sent to this email and not use embedded signing, you need to remove the **clientUserId** and that will get the email sent to the person that needs to sign so they can sign remotely.

Comment: Thanks a lot been struggling with this for a while!

Comment: You are very welcome Aneesha